# подключение одинаковых скриптов несколько раз

Tags: php, javascript

`head` и `footer` расположены в отдельных файлах... из каждого из этого файла подключается одинаковый скрипт `<script type="text/javascript" src="xyz.js"></script>`, так же, в теле может быть подключение этого же скрипта еще из нескольких мест... скажите, играет ли это большую роль? это касается также и `php-файлов` - `include()`. такое массовое подключение одинаковых скриптов

Comment: В `PHP` этот вопрос решается очень просто - [include_once()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include-once.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключение скрипта несколько раз приводит к его повторному выполнению. Ясно, что это может привести к неприятным побочным эффектам.
Например, если данный скрипт привязывает какое-то действие к нажатию на определенный элемент, при нажатии это действие выполнится несколько раз. Вряд ли вы этого хотите.

Что касается `PHP` все намного проще. Вы можете спокойно подключать скрипт в любых местах не задумываясь о том, что он подключится несколько раз. Для этого вместо `include()` следует использовать функцию `include_once()`.
Из [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include-once.php):

> Выражение include_once включает и выполняет указанный файл во время
>   выполнения скрипта. Его поведение идентично выражению include, с той
>   лишь разницей, что если код из файла уже один раз был включен, он не
>   будет включен и выполнен повторно. Как видно из имени, он включит файл
>   только один раз (include once).